# How can I remove an entry in the GRUB boot menu and have another menu item be the default to boot?

Tags: grub, boot-loader

I had Ubuntu on my laptop, then I decided to install Kali Linux latest version 2023 but Ubuntu shows up in boot manager and I want to remove it.

[image: boot manager]

How can I remove this Ubuntu showing up and directly boot into Kali Linux? I already tried changing the boot order, but it didn't help.

Comment: Notice this is not grub menu, this is your system's boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to boot any OS in a multi-boot setup in UEFI mode, typical of any PC from ~2012 or newer, **all you have to do is to set the boot priority at UEFI ("BIOS") settings, Boot menu.**

That you still have the old Grub from your previous Ubuntu installation isn't a problem but it can be removed by running `efibootmgr` with the correct parameters, from your current OS.

Now the problem: Someone using Kali Linux is expected to not be posting trivial questions as this one.

Furthermore, Kali Linux is NOT a replacement for Ubuntu. Kali Linux is NOT a normal desktop Linux distro.

Quoting from the [Kali's developers themselves](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/):

> The fact of the matter is, however, that Kali is a Linux distribution specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is NOT a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution for development, web design, gaming, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I see you still have ubuntu installed, so connect to it and install grub customizer, it will help you change your GRUB list.

sudo apt install grub-customizer

After that, search for grub customizer in your application list, open it and you`ll see something like this

[image]

Select the line from the SO you want to change the position and click in the arrow you need to place it whatever you want.

Hope it helps :)